# How to get the current version of jre installed using batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Well I am writing a batch file where i need to get the current version of the installed jre in my system and then make a decision based on that- I am aware that i can get the current version by querying the registry. The following command gives the below output-

```
reg query "HKLM\Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment"

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment
    Java7FamilyVersion    REG_SZ    1.7.0
    CurrentVersion    REG_SZ    1.7

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\1.7
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\1.7.0
```

But i am unable to get the value 1.7 parsing this output using the

```
for /f "tokens=3"  %%i in ('Command') do echo %%i
```

I want only the "1.7" specific to the current Version and then compare it and make a decision. I am not able to understand what option will get that.
Anyone good in batch commands can please help me out on this ?  Any help will be appreciated. I also tried to parse the output of java -version and get the value.

Comment: Why don't you use java -version ?

Comment: THanks! I found this one - it worked. `for /f tokens^=2-5^ delims^=.-_^" %%j in ('java -fullversion 2^>^&1') do set jver=%%j%%k`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "java -version" command and filter/parse the output.

rem Taking "java -version" output and filter the line containing "Runtime Environme
nt". Taking the the 6th word and echo the part before "_"

```
for /f "tokens=1-10" %%a in ('java -version 2^>^&1 ^| find "Runtime Environme
nt"') do for /f "delims=_" %%x in ('echo %%f') do echo %%x
```